# Select specifics characters with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I would like tu select the specifics characters cm in a specific div and add this in a span.

The html :

```
<div class="fc_img_tooltip_desc" style="line-height:1em;">20X10cm
10X100
50X50
100X100</div>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
function highlight_words(cm , fc_img_tooltip_desc) {
if(keywords) {
    var textNodes;
    keywords = keywords.replace(/\W/g, '');
    var str = keywords.split(" ");
    $(str).each(function() {
        var term = this;
        var textNodes = $(element).contents().filter(function() { return 
this.nodeType === 3 });
        textNodes.each(function() {
          var content = $(this).text();
          var regex = new RegExp(term, "gi");
          content = content.replace(regex, '<span class="highlight">' + term 
+ '</span>');
          $(this).replaceWith(content);
        });
    });
}
}
$(window).onload(function(){ highlight_words(); });
</script>
```

This don't work, i do something wrong.

What i have :

```
<div class="fc_img_tooltip_desc" style="line-height:1em;">20X10cm
10X100cm
50X50cm
100X100cm</div>
```

What i want:

```
<div class="fc_img_tooltip_desc" style="line-height:1em;">20X10 cm
10X100 cm
50X50 cm
100X100 cm</div>
```

Comment: If I may, To clarify the question, you're objective is to get a 'text that has a 'cm' after that'? (e.g 10x20cm)?

Comment: i would like to add space or also a white space between 10x20 and cm in 10x20cm to have a display like this 10x20 cm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select HTML element with [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) then do a replacement on `textContent` property:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.fc_img_tooltip_desc');
el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(/\Bcm/, function(match){
  return ' ' + match; 
})
```

```html
<div class="fc_img_tooltip_desc" style="line-height:1em;">20X10cm
10X100
50X50
100X100</div>
```

Put above script at the bottom of html document or fire this snippet on `DOMContentLoaded` event like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        var el = document.querySelector('.fc_img_tooltip_desc');
        el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(/\Bcm/, function(match){
            return ' ' + match; 
        })
    });
</script>
```

### Update

If you have multiple elements to select, you have to use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        document.querySelectorAll('.fc_img_tooltip_desc').forEach(function(value) {
            value.innerHTML = value.textContent.replace(/\Bcm/gi, function(match) {
                return ' <span class="highlight">' + match + '</span>';  
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I try to add this 
<script type="text/javascript">
        var el = document.querySelector('.fc_img_tooltip_desc');
el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(/\Bcm/, function(match){
  return ' ' + match; 
})
    </script>
on my page, no effect

Comment: No unless you add `i` flag: `/\Bcm/i`

Comment: see on the bottom page here http://www.carrelages-cavallin.fr/carrelage/aspect-ciment-decore/item/24-cementine-20

Comment: this don't work in my case because of css word spacing, and to add a span between cm to have <span>cm</span> perhaps this can work ?

Comment: CSS word spacing doesn't have anything to do with this script. If you want to wrap `cm` in a `span` element then check update. I ran this on your web page with no problem.

Comment: Please watch `g` and `i` flags.

Comment: ok now how i can i have 10x20 CM on eachline i can remove the word spacing

Comment: i have remove word spacing to better understanding

Comment: Let me know if this solution didn't answer your problem.

Comment: see the page it is good but if possible to display 10x20 cm on seperate line ?

Comment: You mean a newline between `10x20` and `cm`?

Comment: no sorry for my english i mean "10x20 cm" on a newline

Answer (score 0):

According to your example in comment and clarification in the question body:

```js
var text = $('.fc_img_tooltip_desc').text();
text = text.replace(/([^\s])cm/gi, '$1 cm<br />');
$('.fc_img_tooltip_desc').html(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fc_img_tooltip_desc" style="line-height:1em;">20X10cm
10X100cm
50X50cm
100X100cm</div>
```

This code is runnable. Is this what you want to achieve?

The 2nd version according to the requirements change in comments:

```js
var text = $('.fc_img_tooltip_desc').text();
text = text.replace('cm', '<span>cm</span>');
$('.highlight').html(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fc_img_tooltip_desc" style="line-height:1em;">
20X10cm
10X100
50X50
100X100
</div>
<span class="highlight"></span>
```

FYI: your JS example has 3 obvious flaws. 1: the function (highlight_words) signature has 2 parameters, but you call the function without any. 2: The 2 signature parameters aren't used in the function body, hence the question - why do you need this signature? 3: the 'keywords' is undefined - not in function body, neither out of the function, thus causing JS warnings and never passing the `if (keywords)` condition. These are general programming issues that have nothing to do with your specific issue, but with basic programming experience. You may need to practice (or/and read about) some more basic programming tasks than manipulate DOM.

Comment: no i would like to just select the characters cm <span>cm</span> thanks

Comment: Added another code snippet, wrapping 'cm' with `<cpan>` instead. Is that really what you want? Can you clarify yourself by describing exact 'input' and 'output' conditions? Like "I have the following example HTML: ....", and "I need to get the following example result by JS/JQuery: ....". Please.

Comment: I have updated the 1st snippet, now you have there exactly what you requested. Please check and feedback.

Comment: Also, I added some general points about the function `fc_img_tooltip_desc` in your question body (see FYI at the bottom).

Comment: yes ok but i need the display on each line
10x20 cm
10x20 cm

Comment: Updated the 1st snippet again, please check. Btw, in HTML newlines and also multiple whitespaces are ignored (except in the `<pre>` element), so you need mention such requirements explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for help and sorry for my poor explication i am french.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can retrieve the text that had a [conversion unit] (in this case 'cm') using match() method.

```
// Check if [measurement] text's had a numeric pattern
// followed by any [conversion unit of cm]
var sMeasurementText = $.trim($('.fc_img_tooltip_desc').text());
var sMeasurementPattern = /^(?:\d+x\d+cm)/i;
console.log(sMeasurementText.match(sMeasurementPattern));
```

from which it will return an [array] at hand like this:

```
["10x20cm", index: 0, input: "10x20cm 10X100 50X50 100X100"]
```

Take note that this pattern will retrieve the '1st' string that matches that condition.

Here's a jsfiddle for further reference: http://jsfiddle.net/fh1hj690/

Hope this helps for your case.